# Input: command not found running python with shell script

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, sh, git-bash

I was just using this shell script to run my python code in ssh and it was working, but I want to run it on my local machine and somehow using Windows and git-bash it is not recognizing my code. I think the problem is in the shell script instead of the python code because it was running correctly before.

**The error:**

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax 
line 1: import: command not found 
line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `(`
line 3: 'def get_stdin():'
```

**The script:**

```
if [[ "$OSTYPE" =~ ^msys ]]; then
  dos2unix *.sh // I've put this in and taken it out and I don't think it does anything 
  py -3 $*
else
  dos2unix *.sh
  python3
fi
./make_voc.py
```

**The relevant Python code**

```
import sys

def get_stdin():
    text = sys.stdin.read()
```

**The command**

```
cat INPUTFILE | ./shellscript.sh > OUTPUTFILE
```

Comment: in your python code add `shebang` for `python`, like `#!/usr/bin/env python` in your 1st line of python file. This is required because your python file is interpreted as shell script by parent shell script.

Comment: I added ````#!/usr/bin/env python3```` but it didn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 0):

1. ensure your codes (both Shell & Python) are in DOS format.
2. call your python code as python3 ./make_voc.py

if still not working then ensure you can run a Hello World code in a Shell script & in a new Python code file separately that you created in Windows (not copied from Linux/Unix). After you got your both code files working then call python code from your shell code.

No 'if'...keep it simple. For example in myShell.sh : (only two lines):

echo Hello World from myShell.sh

python3 myPython.py

you should see both Hello World messages on your screen.

If your shell interpreter doesn't work in your cmd window then you might find it useful to have Windows subsystem for Linux. Refer to canada.ca/en/revenue-agency.html
Default bash in Window 10 is not fully functional like real Bash in Linux. So it can not call your python code.

Comment: You're right they weren't both in DOS format :| thank you!